# How to store phone numbers using BITMAP?

Tags: data-structures, bitmap

How do I store phone numbers where I can efficiently query weather a particular phone number has been used or not?

This was a interview question, I suggested many data structures (tree, trie, compressed trie, skip-list, bloom filter) but he was looking for BITMAP. How do I store phone numbers using bitmap?

Comment: It sounds like he's talking about packing a lot of bool flags so that each phone number indexes a single bit. But this question is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that you didn't mention a hashtable. Seems like a hashtable or bitmap would indeed be ideal for that situation and it probably would be more space efficient and lookups would be somewhat faster to use a bitmap. Trie/compressed trie would likely all be similar to a hashtable in terms of space/time performance. Skip-list and Trees may have even worst performance. A bloom filter is pretty much a cross between a hashtable and a bitmap; it is mostly intended to limit the number of disk accesses and thus is of somewhat limited use in this case.

A bitmap is generally better choice space-wise than a hashtable of used or unused elements if it contains more than approximately `N/log(N)` used or unused elements and becomes ideal* at when a hashtable of either unused or used elements is half full. Resulting in a space saving of upwards of `log_2(N)/2`.*

An example, is if you use a 10 digit phone number and half the numbers are used. It takes about `10^10 bits`. However, storing `5x10^9 numbers` in a hashtable would require roughly `32 bits` for each number resulting in a total of about `1.6x10^11 bits`, which is `16x (log N / 2)` that of a bitmap.

*Assuming a hashtable of unused elements would be used if there were more than`N/2` elements else a hashtable of used elements would be used. Otherwise, the ideal for a bitmap is when the hashtable is full and would result in a space saving of upwards of `log_2(N)`.

Comment: when I mentioned compressed trie, he asked me to code it which i couldn't :(

Comment: Ah, I see. If you are going to mention a data structure it's probably wise idea to have some understanding of what it is. Though understanding it doesn't exactly mean you know how to code it offhand. Also, now I review the Wikipedia article I'm reminded that a compressed trie *generally* gets more space efficient as the number of used or unused elements decreases, making a compressed trie a less than ideal choice in this situation because there likely wouldn't be much compression that could be done. This might be what the interviewer may have been trying to get you to see by coding it.

Comment: Not sure if he wanted to see that...but the reason I suggested compressed trie because most of the time area code (first 3 digits) remains same for phone number.

Comment: Fair point, though how well it works depends on the data. If the intended data structure is a bitmap then it's unlikely to be limited to a small enough area, from which the phone numbers are gathered, to allow for much compression using the area codes. "In use" wording makes me think that either area codes can be ignored completely (all numbers are of the same area code) or there are enough variety in the area codes to have little or no benefits from area codes as you'd need to know all phone numbers in use with a given area code to determine if the number is not in use.

Answer (score 1):

The term "bitmap" is overloaded and has several different meanings. Here, I think the interviewer was probably referring to a *[bitvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)*, an array of bits numbered 0, 1, 2, ..., U. You can use a bitvector to represent a numbers in the range 0, 1, 2, ..., U as follows: if the bit at index i is 0, then i is not present in the set, and if the bit at index i is 1, then i is present in the set. Since you can index into a bitvector and flip bits in time O(1), the runtime of inserting an element, deleting an element, and looking up an element in the set is O(1).

The drawback is that the space usage is always Θ(U) and is independent of the number of elements in the set. If you assume that phone numbers are 10 digits long, you'd need 10,000,000,000 bits = 2,500,000,000 bytes = 2.5GB of space to store the phone numbers using a naive encoding. If you assume that phone numbers can't start with 0, you could shave off 1,000,000,000 bits from the encoding by pretending that the number system starts at 1000000000 rather than 0.

Hope this helps!